# Installing Numpy 1.9.2 on Windows 7

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I'm not sure what is going on with my numpy installation. I recently have been trying to upgrade my numpy and scipy distributions on my windows machine, which is using python 2.7.10

When I run pip to install the package, this is the result:

```
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.9.2.tar.gz (4.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 4.0MB 113kB/s ta 0:00:01                                                                                                                                
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Running setup.py install for numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.9.2
```

However, when I import numpy I get this error:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
    from version import git_revision as __git_revision__
ImportError: cannot import name git_revision
```

Does anyone know what's going on? Is there some dependency I am missing? I do have the `version` package installed on my system.

Comment: Might try a binary build of numpy for win32. See http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.2/

Comment: Can you [add](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31420424/edit) the `numpy/version` content to your question?

Comment: Also, try uninstalling and then re-installing numpy with pip, but then with the verbose option (`-vvv` is fully verbose). I think it's good to see where pip gets your numpy tar.gz file from.

Comment: Hi guys. Still got the same error after installing from the sourceforge superpack.

@Evert-what exactly do you mean? I'm trying to install 1.9.2, which is the latest version. I also already tried the pip uninstall install, did not try the verbose option yet, I'll let you know how that goes.

Comment: SF superpack? You're using pip, right? That shouldn't install from SF. Why not try `pip install https://github.com/numpy/numpy/archive/master.zip` then instead?

Comment: @Matt It's clear that you are using Python 2.7.10 when you are attempting to import numpy-- are you sure, though, that the `version` package isn't installed for a different version of Python?  Sometimes systems have several versions of Python installed (e.g. `2.7` and `2.6`).  Can you show the code you are using to call `pip`?  Also, it might be better to use a `.whl` file, which you can download from here [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy).  If your version of `pip` >= version 6 you can use `.whl`.  Do: `pip --no-index /path/to/downloaded/numpy.whl`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Michael,

I have tried using the whl file found [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy), and I tried to install the mlk-cp27-none whl file. Still got the same error.

Comment: Here was the code I used 

`pip install --no-index "numpy-1.9.2+mkl-cp27-none-win32.whl"
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Processing e:\matt\documents\research\nu\numpy-1.9.2+mkl-cp27-none-win32.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.9.2
    Uninstalling numpy-1.9.2:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.9.2
Successfully installed numpy-1.9.2`

Comment: There's one thing that is odd: the error message says `from version import git_revision as __git_revision__`, but the actual numpy repository shows this code as `from .version import git_revision as __git_revision__` (note the leading dot at `.version`).  I have to go back to numpy 1.7 to find the import shown in the error message, so it sounds like you're bumping into an older numpy version. Try removing the `C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy` by hand.

Comment: Also, have a look at `C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\version.py` and see what version of numpy that states.

Comment: Hi @Evert. Just got the message, I'll check when I'm back at my home computer tonight. Thanks for all your help so far! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hey @Evert, deleting the folder in AppData was the right call, numpy and scipy both work now. I'm guessing an old version of the package was sitting in there and python was loading from there. Any idea why python on windows would do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With much thanks to @Evert, the problem was coming from the numpy folder in the AppData that it was trying to load. In fact there was no **version** file in that folder, so perhaps that is why I was getting the error. Deleting the folder in app data allowed numpy and scipy to import normally.

Does anyone know why python loads packages from the windows app data folder when they are installed in site-package?

Comment: Because that directory happens to be earlier in your `sys.path` than the directory where numpy 1.9.2 is installed. And that may be because of what your `PYTHONPATH` is set to, or how Python is installed. Without knowing what Python you're using, its path, how it was installed initially (and ditto for pip). it's hard to see how this came about.

Comment: Ok, I can take a look into that. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it!